# Smalltalk : best to avoid non-local returns? Algorithm rewrite

Tags: algorithm, smalltalk

This method (from SOM benchmarks) relies on Smalltalk non local returns. Is there a way to produce the same results without them?

```
placeQueenNonLocalReturn: c
    1 to: 8 do: [ :r | 
        (self row: r column: c)
            ifTrue: [
                queenRows at: r put: c.
                self row: r column: c put: false.
                (c = 8) ifTrue: [ ^true ].
                (self placeQueen: c + 1) ifTrue: [ ^true ].
                self row: r column: c put: true ] ].
    ^false
!
```

Note (another question but related): Is it possible to change this code without knowing anything about callers and callees? I guess it should give a better understanding of purpose, but should not the method be self contained regarding my question?

Comment: "but should not the method be self contained?" The important part is describing the interface --- what arguments it accepts (which is obvious from the code), and what is the meaning of returing `false` vs `true`, which is not particularly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You are using the non-local return only to get a quick exit from the 1 to: 8 do: loop.
You can easily write the loop with other syntax, like:

```
exit := false.
row := 1.
[row < 9 andNot: [exit]] whileTrue: [ (self row: r column: c)
            ifTrue: [
                queenRows at: r put: c.
                self row: r column: c put: false.
                c = 8 ifTrue: [ exit := true ] 
                      ifFalse: [ (self placeQueen: c + 1) 
                                    ifTrue: [ exit := true ] 
                                    ifFalse: [self row: r column: c put: true ] ] ].
^exit
```

Note that the call to placeQueen: in the loop seems to be recursive, may be the selector of your method is wrong.

I don´t understand what do you mean with "knowing about callers and callees"... I did a mostly syntactic rewrite on the code.
Same about the self-containment. 
This method is not self-contained, it seems to be part of the 8 Queen problem solution, but relies on (self row: r column: c) to check the validity of a place for a new queen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although not 100% correct (row vs r and row not incremented), it was what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes @JorgeAgra. I am a bit careless when writing code ¨in the air¨ because we are used to try in a test everything that we write, and take advantage of the compiler and debugger... but in this case I missed a part and was too lazy to write the rest in the image

Answer (score 0):

Let's correct a misunderstanding. The code as shown does *not* contain any non-local returns, so it cannot be relying on this feature.

The returns shown are are all just normal returns - they return a result back to the caller.
A non-local return refers to the case where a value is returned to somewhere other than the calling method.

So there is no reason to avoid the returns shown,

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. [ ^true] is a non-local return.

Comment: It would be, if not for the fact that #ifTrue: doesn’t actually create a block context—the compiler knows it isn’t needed.